# create database table with name from variable

Tags: mysql, variables, command

what is the solution? if i need to create database table with name from variable? if i can't use:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE @tablename;", con);
```

My full code looks like:

internal class kurtianketa
    {
        public static string pavadinimas
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    kurtianketa.pavadinimas = textBox1.Text.ToString();
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("database=kursinis_anketa;server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=; Allow User Variables=True");

    MySqlCommand dbCmd2 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO anketos (pavadinimas) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "')", con);
    MySqlCommand dbCmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE @pav ( qnr varchar(255), parametras varchar(255), ats1 varchar(255), ats2 varchar(255), ats3 varchar(255), ats4 varchar(255))", con);

    dbCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@pav", kurtianketa.pavadinimas));

    try
    {

        con.Open();
        dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MySqlDataAdapter DataAdapter1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(dbCmd);
        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(DataAdapter1);


    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "problema su duomenu baze");
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

and i get sintax erorr cose i cant use @pav variable in mysql command:

can someone explane me how should i do it? thex.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly concat the table name into the query's string?

```
MySqlCommand dbCmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + kurtianketa.pavadinimas + " ( 
                                         qnr varchar(255), 
                                         parametras varchar(255), 
                                         ats1 varchar(255), 
                                         ats2 varchar(255), 
                                         ats3 varchar(255), 
                                         ats4 varchar(255)
                                     )", con);
```

Comment: @gogetter if its really solves your problem then why don't you mark it as correct answer?